# Proving Vector Calculus Result Using Divergence Theorem

Tags: vector-analysis

I am working through some problems and have a doubt about how to proceed with the following, as I find the notation somewhat confusing:

> Show that $$\iiint_V \nabla f \, dV = \unicode{x222f}_S \;f \,\hat{n} \; dS$$

It suggests using the result $\nabla \cdot (f \, \vec{c}\,) = \nabla f \cdot \vec{c} \, + \, f\nabla \cdot \vec{c}$.

What I find confusing is the initial triple integral, as it is written: they don't specify the nature of $f$, but I'm assuming it is a scalar field, and so $\nabla f$ would be the gradient of $f$; however, in that case, what exactly is meant by the triple integral over the volume? Am I to understand it as $\iiint_V \nabla f \cdot d\vec{V}$?

Here is my attempt, assuming the above interpretation, and assuming that $d\vec{V}$ would have some sort of analogous definition to $d\vec{S}$ in surface integrals of vector-functions (i.e. $d\vec{S} = \hat{n}\,dS$):

$$ \iiint_V \nabla f \cdot d\vec{V} 
    = \iiint_V \bigl(\nabla f \cdot \hat{n} \bigr) dV
    = \iiint_V \bigl( \nabla \cdot (f\, \hat{n}) - f \, \overbrace{\nabla \cdot \hat{n}}^{=\,0} \bigr) \, dV
    = \iiint_V \nabla \cdot (f \, \hat{n}) \,  dV $$

At which point, we can apply the divergence theorem to show:

$$ \iiint_V \nabla \cdot (f \, \hat{n}) \,  dV
    = \unicode{x222f}_S (f \, \hat{n})\cdot d\vec{S}$$

I am not sufficiently comfortable with the ideas here, nor the notation, to be confident in this interpretation and would appreciate any guidance as to the appropriate interpretation of the question.

EDIT: $f$ apparently is an arbitrary, smooth scalar field and the identity is meant to be understood as a vector identity. This doesn't clarify much for me, but in case it is helpful...

Comment: Is $V$ any specific solid?  Otherwise I am not sure how to extend $\hat n$ to $V$.

Comment: No - there is literally no indication of what V or S are (I am assuming S to be a boundary of V, where conditions for the Divergence Theorem are met).